# Можно ли в Java рисовать на форме при помощи paint() с включенным setUndecorated()?

Tags: java, swing

При включении `setUndecorated()` на форме ничего нельзя отрисовать.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это как? `setUndecorated()` выключает только стандартную рамку, свернуть, развернуть, закрыть, а рисуешь ты на фрейме.

Comment: Если я включаю setUndecorated(), то на фрейме просто ничего не отрисовывается

Comment: Код кинь...

Comment: Код

    public Main()
     {
      setLayout(new BorderLayout());
      setTitle(Settings.title);
      setSize(380, 430);
      setLocationRelativeTo(null);
      setResizable(false);
      setAlwaysOnTop(true);
      setUndecorated(true);
      setVisible(true);
            }

Comment: Ну наверно хорошо, а где ты пробуешь рисовать?

Comment: На JPanel, которая добавлена на форму